# Can't capture output of Java from batch file when invoked from VBA

Tags: java, vba, batch-file

I have a jar file which print a code to console.

To invoke that jar and capture the output, I have a batch file like this.

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if defined CLASSPATH (set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.) else (set CLASSPATH=.)

FOR /R ..\lib %%G IN (*.jar) DO set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%G

set JAR_CMD='java -Xms256M -Xmx256M -classpath D:\libs\Test.jar com.mno.Main %*'

REM ---------PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE---------
FOR /f "delims=" %%J in (%JAR_CMD%) do set "output=%%J"

echo OUTPUT IS %output%
```

It prints the Jar output on console when I run that bat file from cmd. (eg. "OUTPUT IS Hello" where 'Hello' is output of jar)

I have to invoke that batch file from the excel vba by using WshShell. But I got only *"OUTPUT IS "* as result if I run that batch from vba.

<strike>The for loop seems to be causing the problem. I changed `"output=%%J"` to `"output=TESTING"` but it still doesn't set anything into `output variable`.</strike>

**UPDATE: Java is not called from batch file if it is invoked from VBA.** But works if call the batch file directly from cmd windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

I have installed both 32bit /64bit jdk/jre on my 64bit windows 7 (if it matters).

Comment: Since you are using WshShell within Excel VBA, why don't you skip the batch file bit and use something like `Set oExec = Exec(JAR_CMD_x)` then `If Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then sOut = oExec.StdOut.ReadAll()`? sOut should be what you are after

Comment: Vba to Java is okay. But due to the requirements, I need to do that (vba -> batch -> java).

Comment: Java is not called or your .jar file is not executed? The `for /r ..\lib` uses a relative path that implies a current active directory. If the current active directory is not what you think when executed from vba, the code will not find the required elements.

Comment: @MCND I have the required libraries placed at the corrent path. My jar is working properly. I logged to a file in jar and log file is printed if called from cmd windows.

Comment: @MinNaingOo, scenario 1 (call from cmd) - you call the cmd from the same folder contining it and everything executes fine. scenario 2 (vba) - the current active directory is not the cmd folder so `..\lib` does not found the libraries. From here the question if what is not running when called from VBA is the jar file or the java executable.

Comment: @MCND I'm sorry if I don't understand you correctly. Says "lib" are at `C:\myprogram\lib` and bat file at `C:\myprogram\script`. (1) I changed directory in cmd to that `script` folder and run the bat file. It was okay. (2) I give vba WshShell the full file path of the bat file `C:\myprogram\script\run.bat`. It wasn't okay. I created a simple jar which doesn't depend on libraries and only output a line. Then I removed getting libraries from batch file. Still don't get the output if called from vba.

Comment: If the batch file is working in a CMD, how did you execute it in VBA? Do you have `cmd /c ` at the front?

Comment: I use `exec` function of the `WshShell`. I've also tried `run` function of `WScript.Shell` that use `CMD /C`. But they both doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside of code blocks (in this case the for loop) need to be called with delayed expansion.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
<other code>
FOR /f "delims=" %%J in (%JAR_CMD%) do set "output=%%J"
echo OUTPUT IS !output!
```